# Why is my ngModal value getting a string value instead of the boolean value true or false in my html select?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-select

I have the select below and when I change the value my ngModel value comes back with a string, not a boolean

```html
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ceModal.isApproved" (ngModelChange)="markDirty()" name="ceIsApproved">
  <option [ngValue]=null>None selected</option>
  <option value=true>Yes</option>
  <option value=false>No</option>
</select>
```

in ngModelChange I do a simple check to see what 'ceModal.isApprvoed' is and it's "true" and "false" not true and false. How can I keep them as bools?

Comment: I'm guessing `value=true` in your option is a string; you need to use the `markDirty` method to manually set it to a bool depending on the selection. You could also use a checkbox instead.

Comment: I think if I change the 2 value properties to [ngValue] it fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
[ngValue]=true
```

fixes my issue

Answer (score 0):

Bind to value with square brackets: `[value]="false"`

Comment: don't want a string "false"

Comment: And it won't be, it'll be a boolean primitive. For a string "false", you'd have to do `[value]="'false'"`.